# Orient Db AssertionError OCachePointer.incrementReadersReferrer

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

I am running into this assert error in orient db. Anybody seen this before ? Any workarounds?
 I run into this when doing a large insert and simultaneously query for a data.

```
   java.lang.AssertionError
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.cache.OCachePointer.incrementReadersReferrer(OCachePointer.java:92)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.cache.local.OWOWCache.load(OWOWCache.java:790)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.cache.local.twoq.O2QCache.updateCache(O2QCache.java:1155)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.cache.local.twoq.O2QCache.doLoad(O2QCache.java:361)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.cache.local.twoq.O2QCache.load(O2QCache.java:294)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.base.ODurableComponent.loadPage(ODurableComponent.java:148)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OPaginatedCluster.readRecordBuffer(OPaginatedCluster.java:713)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OPaginatedCluster.readRecord(OPaginatedCluster.java:689)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OPaginatedCluster.readRecord(OPaginatedCluster.java:668)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.doReadRecord(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:4203)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.readRecord(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:3819)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.readRecord(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:1409)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx$SimpleRecordReader.readRecord(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:3412)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.executeReadRecord(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:2023)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.tx.OTransactionNoTx.loadRecord(OTransactionNoTx.java:98)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.load(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:1772)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.load(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:103)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.iterator.OIdentifiableIterator.readCurrentRecord(OIdentifiableIterator.java:300)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.iterator.ORecordIteratorClusters.hasNext(ORecordIteratorClusters.java:167)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.serialIterator(OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.java:1636)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.fetchFromTarget(OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.java:1585)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.executeSearch(OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.java:522)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.execute(OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.java:485)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLDelegate.execute(OCommandExecutorSQLDelegate.java:70)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.executeCommand(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:3417)
[catch] at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.command(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:3335)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.query.OSQLQuery.run(OSQLQuery.java:78)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.query.OSQLAsynchQuery.run(OSQLAsynchQuery.java:74)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.query.OSQLSynchQuery.run(OSQLSynchQuery.java:102)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.query.OQueryAbstract.execute(OQueryAbstract.java:33)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.query(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:760)
```

Comment: Is the "select" query made on the class you are inserting with "insert"?

you also tried if you first run insert and then select, the problem does not show up, right? (just to be sure that the problem is due to the "parallel" of the two queries)

Comment: the select is against a different class. They are running in parallel. Once all the inserts are complete, if I do the select, the issues dot not show up. I can't really change the parallel nature of the query as they are originating from two different threads

Comment: Starting from v2.2, the OrientDB SQL executor can decide if execute or not a query in parallel, only if query.parallelAuto setting is enabled. (By default is false). 
did you try to set this parameter to true value?  are there some changed?